# Logging works sometimes, but sometimes not

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have tried to use several Logging-Frameworks like org.apache.log4j.Logger or org.apache.commons.logging.Log. But none of them are working corretly. In our console we didn't see anything, even though the debugger tells that the codes for logging were called (tested with break points).

The codes for logger with the framework log4j is like this:

```
 private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger( TimeMeasurement.class.getSimpleName() );
```

And we used the followng line to print the result:

```
logger.info("Time Measurement Result");
```

The logger.info() was called because the debugger stopped here.

Why didn't we see anything in the console?

The configuration of log4j is like this:

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

We also tried to use

```
System.out.println("Test");
```

to print the result, but still nothing in the console.

But some **other classes** do have the **same loggers** too and they could print in the console with all frameworks above! It is so strange...

Comment: Is this a *Web Application* (e.g. you are using Tomcat) or *Standalone Application*?

Comment: @PaulVargas This is a Standalone Application with Wildfly as Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it should be:

`log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console`

(not `stdout`, but `console`).

**UPD:**

Try also:

```
log4j.rootCategory=info, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

Comment: Thank you @Andremoniy, but it doesn't work:( It is so strange, snce we also have some other classes in the same package. And these classes are using the same framework to log and they are working! Some classes do not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Thank you again @Andremoniy, but it still doesn't work. The problem is that, other frameworks for logging do not work either and some other classes in the same package also contain the same logger and they are working! But some of them do not:(

Comment: hello, now I`m using your configuration and it works:) The problem was, I had several property files, and one overrides the other. So the configuraton was not read correctly:)

Answer (score 1):

try to add something like this:

```
 log4j.logger.your_TimeMeasurement_package_here=INFO, stdout
```

to your log4j.properties file